# read numbers from files and compare them in an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```bash
#!/bin/bash

nomFich="fichier.txt"

n=$(sort $nomFich | uniq | wc -l)

while read nom; do
    read pren
    read score
     if [[ $score -gt 50 ]]; then
        echo $nom
        echo $pren
        echo $score  
    fi
    
done < "StudentThatCompletedtheExam.txt"
```

I'm reading lines from that file nomFich
structured this way:

```
mohamed
ali
90
ali
salem
95
paul
bens
46
```

i want to read it 3 lines at a time so i can stock all variables and then if that 3rd variable named score is greater then 50 I put all the 3 variables to another file.

The Problem is that if statement doesn't work it cannot compare `$score` and `50`
console output is:

```
$ ./test.sh 
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

I tried converting the $score to an int but it doesn't work
and I tried about everything else.
And I want to do it this way because it's very simple for a beginner to understand it.

Comment: I think your file has CRLF newlines. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: The script never uses `$n`.

Comment: See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for info and options for handling CRLF-format files. Using `IFS=$'\r' read ...` might be the best option here (see [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings/67611850#67611850)).

Comment: @Barmar It works it's outputting the error three time which is intended and how to fix it withdos2unix

Comment: @GordonDavisson in Vscode I see it's LF I tried CRLF same problem

Comment: Why is the error intended? The error is because there's an unexpected Carriage Return character in `$score`.

Comment: I solved it thanks guys it I just had to change the file of fichier.txt to LF instead of CRLF in VSCode still didn't understand why exactly.

Comment: @Doom the trailing `\r` on each line means there's a `\r` (CR) on the end of each value read from the file. for the `score` variable the condiitonal looks like: `[[ 90\r -gt 50 ]]` which `bash` treats as `[[ 90 \r -gt 50 ]]` which in turn generates the error stating that `\r is an invalid arithmetic operator`; eliminate the `\r` and the error goes away

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
vim StudentThatCompletedtheExam.txt -c "set ff=unix" -c ":wq"
vim fichier.txt -c "set ff=unix" -c ":wq"
```

I think it is only the file StudentThatCompletedtheExam.txt with the problem, but I have included both files just incase.

That will fix the issue with the eol being dos formatted, then the script shoudl work correctly.  I have tested it on my system, and have been able to replicate the problem, and the fix works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do this with tools better than Bash.

Here is an awk:

```
awk 'FNR%3==1{split("",rec)}
{rec[FNR%3]=$1}
FNR%3==0 && $1>50{print rec[1] ORS rec[2] ORS $1}' file
```

Or a Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\R/).
            each_slice(3){|first,last,score| 
                puts "#{first}\n#{last}\n#{score}" if score.to_i>50} ' file
```

Either prints:

```
mohamed
ali
90
ali
salem
95
```

If you have DOS line endings, you can set the input record separator to filter out the `\r` like so:

```
awk -v FS="\r?\n" 'FNR%3==1{split("",rec)}
{rec[FNR%3]=$1}
FNR%3==0 && $1>50{print rec[1] ORS rec[2] ORS $1}' file
```

The Ruby already handles DOS or Unix line endings since the the split on `\R` is universal.